# android thread start issue

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I am stating a thread to do certain jobs,

```
    Thread download= new Thread("download"){
        public void run(){
            Looper.prepare();
            downloadThreadHandler = new Handler();
            Looper.loop();
        }
    };
    download.start();
```

And I am giving posting Runnables to thread to do tasks inside thread.

```
downloadThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {});
```

When these two snippets are immediate then exception occurs.
If there is some delay between starting thread and posting Runnables, then it works fine.
Also I could not find problem because debugging process adds that delay and it works fine while debugging

Answer (score 0):

Post to thread probably occurs before loop fully started. Delay lets loop start.